# When was it determined that Type 1 Diabetes is an autoimmune disease?

Tags: history, autoimmune, diabetes-mellitus

I just found out today that type 1 diabetes is an autoimmune disease.  When was this discovered?

Comment: It probably would help people answering the question if you could link or quote from the source where you found this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has two answers: The difference was first described in 1936 by Harold Percival Himsworth, which described it in this [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20779994).
At this time it was established that there are two forms of Diabetes, one sensitive to insuline while the other is not.
The terms Diabetes type 1 and 2 where established somewhere between 1974 and 1976, for details see the review "[The discovery of type 1 Diabetes](http://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/50/2/217.full)".

Comment: Thanks.  From the "discovery" article it appears the autoimmune theory really solidified around 1974.

Comment: It takes a while until such a concept is widely accepted.